# Почему не работает эта программка?

Tags: java

Учусь java по книге Шилдта - в книге приведен программка-пример,
пытаюсь ее запустить, а компилятор ошибку выдает.
Подскажите пож. - что пропущено в этой программке?

```
import java.io.IOException;

public class HelloWorld {
  public static void main(String[] args)
          throws java.io.IOException {

      int i;
      System.out.println("Для остановки нажмите клавишу S");

      for (i = 0; (char) System.in.read() i = 'S';
      i++)
      System.out.println("Проход #" + i);
  }
}
```

Comment: А ошибку прочитать-не?

Comment: `for (i = 0; (char) System.in.read() i = 'S';
    i++)` - это только мне кажется странным?)

Comment: 115-я страница Шилдта "Руководство для начинающих"... Уж как есть(((

Comment: возможно проблема в том переменные названы одинаковыми именами, у вас две переменные `i`

Comment: = замените на != и второй раз `i` - зачем? И все же логика кривая будет, ведь `read()` ожидает ввода `Enter`

Comment: Видимо, в книге опечатка. Вместо `i = 'S'` должно быть `!= 'S'`.

Answer (score 0):

Точно - 2 последних ответа верные

> = замените на != и второй раз `i` - зачем? И все же логика кривая будет, ведь `read()` ожидает ввода `Enter`

и

> Видимо, в книге опечатка. Вместо `i = 'S'` должно быть `!= 'S'`.

спасибо)))